# Using single model for multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, single-table-inheritance, sti

I am wondering if it is possible to combine columns from of different tables and use it as one model in Rails. I have two tables below, one holds generic columns and other specialize columns.

```
posts
--------------
id
title
description
created_at
updated_at

jobs
--------------
post_id
category_id
job_type
duration
salary
```

In Rails model,

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
#
end
```

On saving Job model should save columns in respective tables. I thought about using single table inheritance (STI) but look like I can't split columns in multiple tables with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you just need to use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), then you can fill column of `post` on saving `jobs` using the `posts_attributes` key.

**Adding posts to job**

`job[posts_attributes] = [{ :title => "test", :description => "Lorem ipsum"}]`

**Deleting posts from job**

`job[posts_attributes = [{ :id:20, :_destroy => true}]`

Hope that will help you ;)

Comment: Thanks Tronix117. This is exactly what I was looking.